# Servlet null parameter when using textarea instead of input type="text"

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have a problem with parameter passage from JSP page to java Servlet.
This is my JSP code,

```
<form action="textAction" method="post">
     <b>Insert text here</b><br>
           <textarea name="text" rows=3 cols=40></textarea><br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submitButton">
</form>
```

This is my simple Servlet code

```
public class RetrievingAllParams extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID =-4688630293104775447L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
       ` PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         String text = request.getParameter("text");
         out.print(text);
         out.close();
    }
 }
```

}

In this simple case, I want to take the text of the text area and put it on the screen, but in the real project I have to put this text into the database. The problem is that the result of the Servlet call is null.
Someone has a solution for this??

**edit**
if I change textarea with simple input of a form the Servlet works... I don't understand where is the error in my code

Comment: What do you mean by "the result of the Servlet call"? Do you mean `request.getParameter("text")`?

Comment: Assuming that @JonSkeet is correct then make sure that you have requested the page with a parameter "text" (as a POST submission).

Comment: Jon Skett...the String text is null. The function request.getParameter("text") return null

Answer (score 0):

Give FORM tag an id attribute.

```
<form action="textAction" method="post" id="myform" name="myform">
 <textarea name="text1" id="text1" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submitButton">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

**java.lang.String getParameter(java.lang.String name)**

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the
>   parameter does not exist. Request parameters are extra information
>   sent with the request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in
>   the query string or posted form data.

Verify that you've `text` as parameter available in your request before calling `request.getParameter("text")`

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)

Comment: <textarea name="text" rows=3 cols=40></textarea> this is the text parameter that i want to use in the servlet. I think that is an available parameter and that the line String text = request.getParameter("text"); is correct...or no??

Comment: Are you sure that `RetrievingAllParams` servlet mapped as `textAction`??

Comment: This doesn't answer the problem with the code posted so far in the question.